# How do I stop the Invalid Name Error in minecraft pocket edition, even with an appropriate name?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing minecraft pocket edition for a while and got the new update recently. How do I stop the Invalid Name error when I join my little brothers server? I've already seen the no spaces or special characters in your name answers on this website, but they do not work for me.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what name you are trying to use, it may be difficult to diagnose the issue.

Comment: What @TrentHawkins is trying to say is, what name (or names) did you try that didn't work?